# Inno Setup - How to validate serial number online

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, licensing

Using Inno Setup, `setup.exe` was given to a client, according to contract he is allowed only to use 2016 and 2017. But on 01-01-2018 he should not be able to continue with same serial 2017.

How to make the setup.exe by innosetup limited to from and to date?

```pascal
[Setup]
#define SerialNumber "2017"
UserInfoPage=yes

[Code]
function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Serial = '{#SerialNumber}';
end;
```

- setup.exe is executed
- license key is inserted
- after submit, i want to check URL `https://www.example.com/query/license?id=2017`
- if the result is ok or nok based on that the installation continue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with a code from: [Inno Setup - HTTP request - Get www/web content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42805224/850848), you will get something like:

```pascal
[Setup]
UserInfoPage=yes 

[Code]

// Presence of the CheckSerial event function displays the serial number box.
// But here we accept any non-empty serial.
// We will validate it only in the NextButtonClick,
// as the online validation can take long.
function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Serial <> '');
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  Url: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpUserInfo then
  begin
    WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    Url := 'https://www.example.com/serial.php?serial=' +
           WizardForm.UserInfoSerialEdit.Text;
    WinHttpReq.Open('GET', Url, False);
    WinHttpReq.Send('');
    // Depending on implementation of the server,
    // use either HTTP status code (.Status)
    // or contents of returned "page" (.ResponseText)
    // Here we use the HTTP status code:
    // 200 = serial is valid, anything else = serial is invalid,
    // and when invalid, we display .ResponseText
    Result := (WinHttpReq.Status = 200);
    if not Result then
      MsgBox(WinHttpReq.ResponseText, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

A simple server-side validation PHP script (`serial.php`) would be like:

```php
<?

if (empty($_REQUEST["serial"]) || ($_REQUEST["serial"] != "2017"))
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 The serial number is not valid");
    // error message to be displayed in installer
    echo "The serial number is not valid";
}
```

[image]

---

For consideration:

- This validation is not difficult to bypass, i.e. using a proxy server.
- It also does not prevent the user from extracting the files from the installer and installing them manually.
- You may consider instead an on-line download of the actual files only after validating the serial number.
- Or downloading some license file that the application will require for functioning. You need that anyway, if you want to enforce the application to stop working once the license expires.
- Or you can also encrypt the installer and make the online service return the decryption password:
  [Read Inno Setup encryption key from Internet instead of password box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68077131/850848)

---

For a similar question, see also
[How to store serial numbers in a Sharepoint List, for to call from Inno Setup and verify if is autorized user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34690961/850848)