# Inno Setup. Is it possible to ask for user input in setup before installation and then compare the input to a raw on internet?

Tags: installation, compare, inno-setup, license-key, pastebin

Inno Setup. Is it possible to ask for user input in setup before installation (eg. Activation/License Key) and then compare the input to a raw on internet (url like pastebin/github)?
I dont know if this is possible to do in Inno Setup. I'm new to Inno Setup, this is the coding which runs the function that I want in batch script:

```
//Prompt user input
set /p lkey=Please Enter the License Key:

//Raw Source
Set "url=https://pastebin.com/raw/jzpBQaDR"

//Download the Key into txt and save it
for %%# in (%url%) do ( set "File=%tmp%\%%~n#.txt" )
Call :Download "%url%" "%File%"
set /P var=< "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\jzpBQaDR.txt"
rem for /F "tokens=1" %%a in ("%var%") do 

//Compare the Key (User Input and Raw)
IF %lkey%==%var% (
//continue installation
.....
) ELSE (
//abort installation
......
)
```

Comment: See [Inno Setup - How to validate serial number online](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46360052/850848).